# pytest-django doesn't discover my tests, unless explicitly invoked

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django

I just started using Django, and have only used PyTest for a couple of projects, but I love them both.

So I was happy to discover the **pytest-django** plugin that seems incredibly straight-forward and easy to use.

Per [part 5 of the Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial05/) (I've been working through that), I've written a number of tests in `mysite/polls/tests.py`.  These run flawlessly with the built-in test runner.

So, now with **pytest** and **pytest-django** installed, when I run `py.test` from within the project root, or `py.test polls` I get nothing:

[image: collected 9 items]

When I explicitly invoke my file with `py.test polls/tests.py`, I get the colorful expected output:

[image]

What have I missed?  I've followed the set up to the letter, and the [Basic Usage docs](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#usage) of the plugin attest that a simple `py.test` should automatically find my tests. Why aren't they being found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following pytest naming conventions, try renaming your test file to:
test_[some text here].py

For example:
test_polls_unittests.py

Read more about pytest - tests naming conventions [here](http://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery).

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Renamed `tests.py` to `test_polls.py` and all are now auto-detected and run by the `py.test` command.  Thank you!

Comment: Yay! Glad to hear :)

Comment: Alternatively, you can add `python_files = tests.py test_*.py` to the `[pytest]` section of your project's `pytest.ini` file. See issue [pytest-django/#67](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/issues/67) and the [related pytest docs](http://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html#changing-naming-conventions).